# While trying to have group video chat using the opentok multiple stream with null streamId gets added and video goes blank some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, opentok

[image]I am trying to implement group video functionality and I have following code

```
class App extends Component {
  this.state = {
     subscribers: [],
     subscriberVideos: [],
     screenVideo: undefined,
     publisherVideo: undefined,
     publisher: undefined,
  }
}
```

```
async start() {
  let publisher = OT.initPublisher(null, this.defaultPublisherProps, error => {
    if(error) {
    }  
  })
 publisher.on('videoElementCreated', this.onPublisherVideoElement);
 this.state.otSession.publish(publisher, error => {
    if (error) {
   }
   this.setState(() => {
     return { publisher: publisher };
   }
  }
}
```

```
onPublisherVideoElement = event {
  this.setState(() => {
   return { publisherVideo: event.element }
   });
  }
}
```

```
onPublisherScreenElement = event => {
  this.setState(() => {
    return { screenVideo: event.element }
 }
}
```

```
onSubscriberVideoElement = event => {
   this.setState(() => {
      return { 
        subscriberVideos: [...this.state.subscriberVideos, event.element]
      }
     }
   })
}
```

```
onSessionStreamCreated = event => {
  let subscriber = this.state.otSession.subscriber(event.stream, null, this.defaultSubscriberProps, error => {
     if (error) {
     }
    if (event.stream.videoType == 'screen') {
      subscriber.on('videoElementCreated', this.onPublisherScreenElement);
      this.setState(() => {
        return { screenSubscriber: subscriber };
      })
   } else {
     subscriber.on('videoElementCreated', this.onSubscriberVideoElement);
       if (this.props.mdm === "m") {
          this.setState((prevState) => {
             return {
               subscribers: [...this.state.subscribers, subscriber]
             }
          }
        }
     else {
       return { subscribers: [...this.state.subscribers, subscriber] }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

While showing subscribers I am doing

```
showSubscribers() {
    return this.state.subscribers.filter(subscriber => subscriber.stream !== null).map((subscriber, index) => {
       return(
          <VideoSubscriber
             key={index}
             otok={this.otok}
             subscriber={this.state.subscribers[index]
             subscriberVidoe={this.state.subscriberVideos[index]
            />
       )
    }
}
```

But at random times the video goes black and also while some of the subscriber refresh the page it goes blank creates multiple subscirber with null stream.
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to handle the 'streamDestroyed' event and remove your subscribers. This is probably why you're getting blank subscribers when people leave.

Also video going black randomly could be happening because you're falling back to audio-only mode. This happens if your network has lots of packet loss, then it will drop the video and try to only send audio. You can handle the videoDisabled event and look at the reason 'quality'. More details [here](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/subscribe-stream/js/#:%7E:text=%22quality%22%20%E2%80%94%20The%20OpenTok%20Media,based%20on%20stream%20quality%20changes.&text=By%20default%2C%20the%20Subscriber%20displays,with%20this%20reason%20is%20dispatched.)

Comment: How do i remove the VideoElementCreated when I destroy subscriber.

Comment: Do you mean how do you remove the videoElementCreated event? You can use subscriber.off()

Comment: How do i unsubscribe those subscriber whose stream is null. When i refresh some of them have null streams

Comment: subscribers are created by calling subscribe when you have a stream. I'm not sure how you end up with a subscriber without a stream...